# How to create new users with JMeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I have to perform load and performance testing of my new site which requires login functionality. I am using JMeter to test performance and load. Can you please send me the details of how I can create multiple users to the database by using JMeter, so that I can use them to login multiple users at a time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**JMeter is a Load testing tool and not a data creation tool**.

It should be used for load testing and not functional aspects.
Though it can be used for data creation because of its record and replay feature. (of course with parametrization)

To create data,

1. you need to record create user scenario using JMeter.
2. parametrize add user request (username,details)with csv data set config element.
3. add CSV data set config with required no. of entries (500 in your case) where each line represents user details,
   user1,India,passwd1
   user2,US,passwd2
4. run script with 500 threads (not advisable but a possible way) or single thread with 500 loop count.

This will create users with data from csv. After that you can load test your website.

Comment: I followed your instructions as you described above, but couldn't sign up new users.

Comment: I pass the first name, last name, username, email and password in csv files. All informations of users passed but the _csrf is not picking up. Kindly give me solution

Comment: Can you provide request, testplan, threadgroup snapshots with parametrization you did? if possible here or at nachiket.kate90@gmail.com.

Comment: I have sent you snapshots to your provided email.

Comment: Yup, I'll check and reply asap.

Comment: I have seen those snapshots. Parameterization is correct but What is csrf_ field, it is dynamically generated or session id or something else? I have sent you chat invitation on yahoo id. if possible join chat room on Stack overflow with name JMeter_NK.

Comment: csrf is a spring securit check which we are using in our site. Kindly guide me how can i test my site. How can i by pass this security check to login multiple users at a same time. I passed correct usernames and passwords but csrf didn't allow to access.

Comment: Is it possible to send me your script? (If its not confidential). I'll have a look once and let you know If I get something.

Comment: Sure, I have sent you email at nachiket.kate90@gmail.com.

Comment: @NachiketKate - Here is it require to add 500 CSV controller to jmeter plan? How jmeter understands that for 1st thread it need to use first login and password , for second thread it should pick values from second row?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set following things to your Jmeter test plan :

1 - Thread group - Here you can set parallel users[Ex: 450 users] , ramp up period[Ex: 300 seconds] and loop count[Ex : 5]

2 - Login page with get and post method

3 - Listener like summary report , table , tree or other which is suitable for you.

Reference detailed link for login process : [How to do login using Jmeter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/80479-how-to-use-jmeter-for-login-authentication)

Please let me know if you have any confusion during your load testing.

Comment: I want to perform testing with 500 users but first I have to create these 500 users email and passwords. My question is how can i automaticaly create user in my data base. So i can use those users to test performance and load testing.

Comment: you can use single user name and pass and put load with 500 sampler.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create users directly in database the correct JMeter Test Element is [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler which allows to execute arbitrary SQL queries against any database which supports JDBC protocol.

1. Download a relevant JDBC driver for your database and drop it to /lib folder of your JMeter installation
2. Restart JMeter if it's running (jars loading isn't dynamic and performed on start)
3. Add [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) element to your Test Plan or Thread Group and populate at least the following fields:

   - Variable Name
   - Database URL
   - JDBC Driver Class
   - Username and Password
4. Configure JDBC Request to insert email/password pairs. You can use it in conjunction with [CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) so user credentials could be read from CSV file.
5. See [Building a Database Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) guide or select `File -> Templates -> JDBC Load Test` to get idea on how your Test Plan should look like.